# How to find text position and boundary in iText 7

Tags: java, itext7

**As the comments suggested, this work is difficult, so I want to solve it step by step to see the limitation. Firstly I will focus on the 1st question below.**

**Origin:**

I want to replace text in PDF file for translation purpose, e.g. convert a English PDF into Chinese PDF.

My solution is:

1. find all text with their position rectangle
2. fill all rectangles with white color
3. draw translated text back into corresponding rectangle(with proper recalculated font size)

Specifically, I implement IEventListener interface to get render info, and use this render info to find text with position rectangle.

But I encountered some questions:

1. with render info, I cannot get the exact position of text(the start point is accurate, but the end point sometimes is inaccurate)
2. the font size varies among languages and fonts, e.g. font size 18 may take more space in one font of one language than another font in another language.
3. it is difficult to merge lines, or recognize paragraphs (text in different lines which should be translated as a chunk)

Is there a better way to achieve my goal than current solution?

Or, any one can provide some suggestions with above questions?

**UPDATED**:

example of the 1st question:

I just record the text with their position encountered in render, and draw a rectangle around each text block. The code is:

Main in Main.java

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcFileName), new PdfWriter(destFileName));
SimplePositionalTextEventListener listener = new SimplePositionalTextEventListener();
new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener).processPageContent(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
List<SimpleTextWithRectangle> result = listener.getResultantTextWithPosition();

int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
for(SimpleTextWithRectangle textWithRectangle: result) {
    R += 40; R = R % 256;
    G += 20; G = G % 256;
    B += 80; B = B % 256;
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(pageNumber));
    canvas.setStrokeColor(new DeviceRgb(R, G, B));
    canvas.rectangle(textWithRectangle.getRectangle());
    canvas.stroke();
}

pdfDoc.close();
```

SimplePositionalTextEventListener.java(`implements IEventListener`):

```
private List<SimpleTextWithRectangle> textWithRectangleList = new ArrayList<>();

private void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    if (renderInfo.getText().trim().length() == 0)
        return;
    LineSegment ascent = renderInfo.getAscentLine();
    LineSegment descent = renderInfo.getDescentLine();

    float initX = descent.getStartPoint().get(0);
    float initY = descent.getStartPoint().get(1);
    float endX = ascent.getEndPoint().get(0);
    float endY = ascent.getEndPoint().get(1);

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(initX, initY, endX - initX, endY - initY);

    SimpleTextWithRectangle textWithRectangle = new SimpleTextWithRectangle(rectangle, renderInfo.getText());
    textWithRectangleList.add(textWithRectangle);
}

public List<SimpleTextWithRectangle> getResultantTextWithPosition() {
    return textWithRectangleList;
}

@Override
public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
    renderText((TextRenderInfo) data);
}

@Override
public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)));
}
```

SimpleTextWithRectangle.java

```
private Rectangle rectangle;
private String text;

public SimpleTextWithRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, String text) {
    this.rectangle = rectangle;
    this.text = text;
}

public Rectangle getRectangle() {
    return rectangle;
}
```

The file is:
[PDF file](https://github.com/voidmagic/pdf-parser/blob/master/data/chinese.pdf)

After process, the header is:
[image]
As we can see, there are some hidden texts which can be found in render info, but invisible in PDF reader applications. And if we dig into each text block, we can see the `renderInfo.getText()` sometimes can not exactly match the text we saw in PDF.

After process, the footer is:
[image]
As we can see, the rectangle boundary can not fully cover the text, that is **what I mentioned in question 1**.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The difficulties you met and describe are inherent to the PDF format. You are trying to do something that no one has done before. Sometimes that's an indication that it can't be done.

Comment: Ad **1**: this obviously is not intended. Please share example pdfs for which this happens, and indicate for what text the end position is wrong. (There are some special cases with glyphs drawn outside their character box. This is hard to fix. But if that is not the case for your examples, a fix may be feasible.) Add **2**: this may be true, the definition of "font size" has a certain subjective component. As you show no example, though, we cannot tell whether you determine the font size correctly. Ad **3**: this is a natural part of your task.

Comment: *"Is there a better way to achieve my goal than current solution?"* - well, you can improve the results by instead of *filling all rectangles with white color* actually *removing the text objects*. That requires some more low-level operations, though. *"some suggestions with above questions"* - that's difficult as **1** and **2** are somewhat vague (no examples, no code) and **3** is merely the description of a subtask of for project.

Comment: A better way to achieve your goal: your PDF is most likely generated from another source format like MS Word or HTML. Do the translation in that other format, and then convert to PDF again. If you have access to the source documents then this is the easiest way.

Comment: I removed my down-vote because the question was made a lot more interesting after the update. Still, I agree with @AmedeeVanGasse that it's better to translate the PDF at the source, and create a new PDF from scratch. Regarding detecting paragraphs, see https://youtu.be/lZnbhnU4m3Y Also search for Stack Overflow answers by Joris Schellekens. He has done a lot of work in the area of structure recognition in unstructured PDF's.

Comment: @mkl I have posted an example for the first case to show the unexpected text position. Can you figure out the reason of that case please?

Comment: Concerning the hidden texts in the header - indeed, text extraction usually extracts **all** text drawn and doesn't care whether it's eventually visible in a viewer or not; it is like [Ctrl-A] in a PDF viewer in that regard. If you want only the visible text, you'll have some filtering ahead of you. You might be interested in numerous questions by [Dmitry K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9123040/dmitry-k) about filtering invisible text during text extraction (he uses PDFBox but the different causes for invisibility of the text examples he stumbled across may give you some head start).

Comment: Concerning the problems in the footer I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incorrect box coordinates are an effect of a bug in the iText 7 CMap handling.

#### The bug

When parsing the named **Encoding** CMap of a Type 0 font, e.g. **GBK-EUC-H**, the `else` branch of this `CMapEncoding` constructor is used:

```
public CMapEncoding(String cmap, String uniMap) {
    this.cmap = cmap;
    this.uniMap = uniMap;
    if (cmap.equals(PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H) || cmap.equals(PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_V)) {
        cid2Uni = FontCache.getCid2UniCmap(uniMap);
        isDirect = true;
        this.codeSpaceRanges = IDENTITY_H_V_CODESPACE_RANGES;
    } else {
        cid2Code = FontCache.getCid2Byte(cmap);
        code2Cid = cid2Code.getReversMap();
        this.codeSpaceRanges = cid2Code.getCodeSpaceRanges();
    }
}
```

Now `FontCache.getCid2Byte(cmap)` uses a `CMapCidByte` to build the mapping in:

```
public static CMapCidByte getCid2Byte(String cmap) {
    CMapCidByte cidByte = new CMapCidByte();
    return parseCmap(cmap, cidByte);
}
```

One peculiarity of `CMapCidByte` (and probably other CMap classes) is that it stores the mapping inverse:

```
private Map<Integer, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
[...]
void addChar(String mark, CMapObject code) {
    if (code.isNumber()) {
        byte[] ser = decodeStringToByte(mark);
        map.put((int)code.getValue(), ser);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's done this way because the most often used lookup direction is the other way around. And this is ok as long as the original mapping is injective, i.e. all keys are mapped to different values.

*Unfortunately CMaps do not need to be injective.* E.g. for **GBK-EUC-H** we have cidrange entries

```
<21> <7e> 814
```

and

```
<aaa1> <aafe> 814 
<aba1> <abc0> 908
```

When importing this encoding, therefore, the latter mappings overwrite many of the mappings of the character codes 0x21..0x7e.

#### Effect on text extraction bounding boxes

In the document at hand there indeed is a font with encoding **GBK-EUC-H** used in the footer text. Thus, for this font many of the single-byte codes 0x21..0x7e are missing from iText's information about the font.

This range of codes encodes proportional Western characters in an otherwise monospaced font, in particular the alternative codes 0xaaa1..0xaafe and 0xaba1..0xabc0 encode the same Western characters as monospaced characters.

In the footer region of your example document these proportional Latin characters are used. Due to the missing mappings, these characters in some iText 7 code paths are replaced by *replacement character symbol* (e.g. text extraction itself does not return the Western characters but "�" instead), in some paths they are completely lost (e.g. when the length of the text chunks is calculated, these Western characters are ignored).

Therefore, the length of character chunks is calculated incorrectly and the bounding boxes, consequentially, are mis-sized and misplaced.

This also explains why the misplaced bounding boxes on each line start at the first occurance of Western characters on that line, and also why the most box size is missing on lines with the most Western characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have looked into the PDF encoding and tried to avoid the mis-sized but failed. Can you provide a solution for this example please?

Comment: I'm afraid that bug simply has to be fixed in the iText sources, I don't see an immediate work-around without effectively re-programming a substantial part of the classes in question. Furthermore, a proper fix must also include checking whether there are any related code blocks which also implicitly assume encodings to be injective. When stepping through the code, I got the impression that e.g. for some text extraction operations data is mapped back and forth via the encoding. This also has to be changed as it may change contents for non-injective encodings.